# How to retrieve a value from js file?

Tags: php, javascript

Basically my question is **How do you get the value of a variable inside a js file.**

E.g

```
var now = (new Date() - 0);

other_var = 'Whats up';//how to pull the value of the other_var which is 'Whats Up'

key.embed();
```

How do get the value of the `other_var` using php? I only need the value of the variable which is 'whats up'.

Made some digging on my own, now I am able to get the content of the js file using `file_get_content` function in php, just don't know how to pull get the variable and pull its value.

Comment: That can be really difficult, depending on how the JS file is structured. Can you provide some more details about it?

Comment: @WonderingCoder My guess is that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @MaxArt the content of the js file has 388 lines. Its an extension of another js files so it full of methods in it. The js file start with this: if (top.myvar === undefined) {

Comment: `var now = (new Date() - 0);`? What? Do you mean `var now = new Date().getTime();`?

Comment: @WonderingCoder Do you just want to retrieve the initial definition of the values of the variables? Are all those variables defined like in your examples? Are they all primitive values (numbers, strings, booleans) or there can be other values, like that variable `now`? This is the kind of details I was talking about.

Comment: @DaveRandom It works. Try it! Javascript automatically converts `Date` objects to integers representing the epoch time when used with math operators. You can even subtract two dates and get the difference in milliseconds between them.

Comment: @MaxArt I know it *works*, it just looks horrible and confusing to others while being semantically identical. Just a best practice comment more than anything else.

Comment: @DaveRandom LOL ok, but then you'd be shocked if you'd see how many times I've used `+new Date()` in my code :) It's way faster to type, after all.

Comment: @MaxArt I've no problem with `valueOf()` as part of a larger expression, it's just when all you want is the value you should make it obvious what you are doing. Subtracting `0` from anything makes no sense so some other developer may come along and remove that part of the expression thinking it's useless, that's what I don't like about it.

Comment: @DaveRandom Nobody touches my code, NOBODY! RAWR! Lol, JK, but honestly, if a coder doesn't understand a simple thing like that, then I don't think is *worth* enough to touch my code. This, however, applies to just my particular situation, and may vary for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  $file = file_get_contents('myfile.js');

  $varNameToFind = 'other_var';

  $expr = '/^\s*(?:var)?\s*'.$varNameToFind.'\s*=\s*([\'"])(.*?)\1\s*;?/m';

  if (preg_match($expr, $file, $matches)) {
    echo "I found it: $matches[2]";
  } else {
    echo "I couldn't find it";
  }
```

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rApVNx)

Something like that? Note that it would only find string values as it looks for quotes, and there are various holes in it that allow it to match a few things that are syntactically invalid Javascript and it will fall down when there are escaped quotes in the string - but as long as the JS is valid, that should find the first place in the file where a string value is assigned to the named variable, with or without a `var` keyword.

**EDIT**

[A much better version](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MbD7mM) that only matches syntactically valid Javascript strings and should match any valid single strings including those with escaped quotes, although it still won't handle concatenation expressions. It also gets the actual value of the string as it would be when loaded into Javascript - i.e. it interpolates escape sequences as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings).

Answer (score 1):

Just look up "other_var = " and then check what comes after it... Get the file with

```
$content = file_get_contents(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I assume the file contents is as you described:

```
    var now = (new Date() - 0);

other_var = 'Whats up';//how to pull the value of the other_var which is 'Whats Up'

key.embed();
```

then I can suggest you use the following:

```
    $data = file_get_contents("javascriptfile.js"); //read the file
//create array separate by new line
//this is the part where you need to know how to navigate the file contents 
//if your lucky enough, it may be structured statement-by-statement on each
$contents = explode("\n", $data); 
$interestvar = "other_var";
$interestvalue = "";
foreach ($contents as $linevalue)  
{
    //what we are looking for is :: other_var = 'Whats up';
    //so if "other_var" can be found in a line, then get its value from right side of the "=" sign
    //mind you it could be in any of the formats 'other_var=xxxxxx', 'other_var= xxxxxx', 'other_var =xxxxxx', 'other_var = xxxxxx', 
    if(strpos($linevalue,$interestvar." =")!==false){
        //cut from '=' to ';'
        //print strpos($linevalue,";");
        $start = strpos($linevalue,"=");
        $end = strpos($linevalue,";");
        //print "start ".$start ." end: ".$end;
        $interestvalue = substr($linevalue,$start,$end-$start);
        //print $interestvalue;
        break;
    }
}
if($interestvalue!=="")
print "found: ".$interestvar. " of value : ".$interestvalue;
```